# Feed empty list to (multidimensional) tensorflow placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Python, I am trying to feed an empty list into a multidimensional tensorflow placeholder with a first dimension of `None`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = [0,1,2]
b = [[4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
c = []

# 1-D and 2-D placeholders
p_1D = tf.placeholder(shape=(None),   dtype=tf.float32)
p_2D = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,3), dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(p_1D, feed_dict={p_1D:a})) # prints [0.,1.,2.]
    print(sess.run(p_2D, feed_dict={p_2D:b})) # prints [[4.,5.,6.],
                                              #         [7.,8.,9.]]
    print(sess.run(p_1D, feed_dict={p_1D:c})) # prints []
    print(sess.run(p_2D, feed_dict={p_2D:c})) # raises ValueError
```

Specifically, the error that is raised is `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_3:0', which has shape '(?, 3)`.

From this, I can see that an empty list can be fed to a placeholder if it has only 1 dimension (of `None`), but higher-dimensional placeholders do not seem to allow it.  Is there a way to allow higher-dimensional placeholders to accept an empty list as input?

(And yes, I know, it may seem silly to want to input an empty list, but it would still help if there is a solution to this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feed_dict={p_1D: np.zeros(shape=(0,), dtype=np.float32), p_2D: np.zeros(shape=(0, 3), dtype=np.float32)}` etc.

Comment: Hm, interesting.  I was not aware of that functionality in numpy. Also, I think you mean `p_2D`.